# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, importerror

I had this error when import csv2.
I already run command "pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.9", "pip install opencv-python=4.4.0.40"
But had the same error.
My python version:3.8.3

Comment: Please include the full error.

Comment: If you are really despertate, you could just instalo It from GitHub...

Comment: See the related question at https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/  You are probably missing  Visual C++ redistributable 2015

Comment: Your title says cv2 . Is it a typo or ??

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I solved the problem.

Comment: @NRR I have the same problem how did you solve it?